# Что добавить для вывода только значений false?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class StringProcessor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "asd oOsdwe ertyu ghjLK Ewesldk";
        String substrings[] = text.split(" ");
        for (String word : substrings) {
            String regex = "[AaOrK]";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
            boolean res = m.find();             
            System.out.print("       returns: " + "  " + res);
        }
    }   
}
```

Этот код проверяет текст на наличие букв [AaOrK]. Мне нужно, чтобы выводились только неверные значения.

Comment: этот код проверяет текст на наличие букв [AaOrK]
мне нужно чтоб неверные значения только выводились

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В таком случае делайте вывод на экран только слов, для которых метод `find` вернул `false`:

```
String text = "asd oOsdwe ertyu ghjLK Ewesldk";
String substrings[] = text.split(" ");
String regex = "[AaOrK]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
for (String word : substrings)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
    if (!m.find())
    {
        System.out.print("Not found for " + word);
    }
}
```

Создание `Pattern`-a имеет смысл вынести за цикл: незачем создавать его каждый раз заново.

Comment: да помогло большое спасибо)

Comment: @ДімаСтан на здоровье. Если ответ вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как подходящий (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

А в чем конкретно проблема?

```
boolean res = m.find();
if (!res) { // res == false
    System.out.print("       returns: " + word);
}
```

[Пример на ideone](https://ideone.com/B75X1X).

Comment: а чтоб оно выводило просто строчкой без false

Comment: @ДімаСтан вы знаете `java`? обновил ответ. Не забудьте отметить один из ответов как правильный галочкой напротив.